# How to output cache key to GITHUB_OUTPUT in Github Cache action?

Tags: caching, github-actions

In my Github workflow, I am using cache across two jobs. The cache key is generated with the help of `${{ hashFiles(...) }}` function. In the second job I need this cache key name in order to skip repeated action for retrieving arguments for `hashFiles`, and go straight to downloading the cache. But I can't do it, [why doesn't this action output a cache key name?](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#output-parameters-for-the-cache-action)

Comment: That's a Boolean value. Can you not use the same key again for the second job? Any issues there?

Comment: I have provided the link to prove that the output is only consists of cache miss/hit flag. I don't use it as a key.

Comment: Well, then it's a feature request for that action. You may [create an issue](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/new/choose) on the repo if there isn't one already. You may also calculate it in a separate step and use that across jobs. Here's an [example](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNT8FqQjEQvOcrBitYhRcPvQUqUmhrL560V4nplqS+JuImPuTx/t2k1ad72d2Z2RnW619SWGi2QgSv0ITD7rsOzebL8V5Hk+GfsGUlgEgcSwcOyXNV1GmbfExVrQsn/jiOtOd/GVDB3/xxqXytQMYGDGzGn4dtizK8uZr4cTSZjMbougFmMwzfP1aL9cvmdfkpesvExAraRBc8T402lubHp96+cdGqfgPyF1ZB3iE7OimUVPJHWZJz3NX+AVLKMy06S/U=) with env var (not tested).

Comment: Here's an [example](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJytUMFKAzEQvecrHkuhWtgV9RawiAetJz3snkRKmo0kdk2WTuIipf9uEutW9KAHc8hkZl7mvXlWvCiOhSDNmLMcg9usnzo3LFtDvfAylp/dijgDYjxNEdgES2VCh1WwPpSd8Ip8buXLBd8HTx9gQMfpHJPtFuRVT1XKqz0mJ9jtWMbm/ue3EvYgDvtjWp7njYWohUNJ7VCk+kWiSY9r0yk6ms5m0+M4vsB8jmJyc1svmqvlXVPfN3XBRqJAijiE9MZZOpFCanX5ej5yDMZrPmZANCYuVH2prNXbXzaMFp79aqFVqo1qHpLfjwdTv3nzf5IzX5XYfkh+B68pmUU=) with output parameter (not tested).

Comment: `hashFiles` function is not defined outside of cache action.

Comment: Alternatively, you can calculate it yourself as described under [`hashFiles`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#hashfiles) and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [why doesn't this action output a cache key name?](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#output-parameters-for-the-cache-action)

This question is well-suited for that action. You may [create an issue](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/new/choose) on its repo (if there isn't one already) to ask this or maybe suggest it as a feature.

---

Apart from that, apparently [`hashFiles`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#hashfiles) seems to work only in certain contexts i.e. it cannot be used in a separate step to calculate it once and then shared across jobs via an output parameter.

However, you may calculate it manually in a separate step without `hashFiles` as described in the docs:

> This function calculates an individual SHA-256 hash for each matched file, and then uses those hashes to calculate a final SHA-256 hash for the set of files. If the `path` pattern does not match any files, this returns an empty string. For more information about SHA-256, see "[SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)."

For example, in Bash you can do something like this using `find` and `sha256sum` utilities and then [share the output between jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs):

```yaml
FILENAME="<FILENAME>"
COMBINED_HASHES=$(echo $(find . -type f -name "$FILENAME" -exec bash -c "sha256sum {} | cut -d ' ' -f1" \;) | tr -d '\n')
HASH=$(sha256sum <<< "$COMBINED_HASHES" | cut -d ' ' -f1)

echo "HASH=$HASH" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

Depending on your use case, you may further refine it accordingly.

---

**UPDATE** (May 10th, 2023)

Another solution could be to use https://github.com/actions/github-script with [`glob`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/glob) which provides an implementation for [`hashFiles`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/457303960f03375db6f033e214b9f90d79c3fe5c/packages/glob/src/glob.ts#L29) also.

Here's a working example:

```yaml
name: github_script_hash_files_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  hash:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      result: '${{ steps.hash.outputs.result }}'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Hash
        id: hash
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          result-encoding: string
          script: |
            return glob.hashFiles('**/README.md');

  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [hash]

    steps:
      - name: Check
        env:
          HASH: '${{ needs.hash.outputs.result }}'
        run: |
          echo "HASH: [$HASH]"
```